# using webbrowser in python to authenticate

Tags: python

I am working on an app where a string is taken as an input and the program automatically opens a browser and searches for the string.The problem I am facing is since I am behind a proxy that requires authentication,before the search results come an alert window opens asking for username and password... which I don't want the user to fill and waste his time. instead if this was stored somewhere I could make my program fill this authentication detail automatically.. Is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the page uses HTTP authentication. If you don't need to actually open a real browser, you could search for the string in python.

[requests](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) makes working with HTTP authentication really easy:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))
# search for your string in response.contents
```

Comment: but it is necessary that i open the browser... any thoughts on that?

Comment: Of course not, if all you want to do is search for a string in a specific page. Any http client will do.